# Looking for a .NET version of PHPMotion

Tags: asp.net, media

I realize that there is not .NET "Version" but I'm looking for an app similar to PHPMotion that runs in ASP.NET.  Does anyone know of something like this?

Comment: I found this too, but there are no screenshots to show if it's what I'm looking for.  Is this similar to PHPMotion?
http://www.mediasoftpro.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this one...

http://www.xigla.com/absolutevc/

Comment: That's a good find, however I'm not sure if I'm willing to spend that kind of $$.  Yeah yeah, I know... I'm cheap... but if PHPMotion is FREE, I'm hoping to find something in .NET that's equivalent.  Maybe not totally free, but not $300 either.